# command \todo already defined, but where? Could I overwrite?

Tags: pdftex, packages, todonotes

I got this error when compiling recipe "pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex x2" on the visual studio code of windows10.

```
 LaTeX Error: Command \todo already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

The code is the same as I compiled on the visual studio code of
ubuntu18. I am wondering how to overwrite the "\todo" command that I don't know where-else was it defined. ( It was never a problem on ubuntu!)

Ps. Part of my source code:

```
%% -------------------------------
%% |    My packages /commands    |
%% -------------------------------
% track changes
    %\usepackage{changes}       % highlight changes
    \usepackage[final]{changes} % don't highlight changes

% tables
    \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}

% pseudocode
    \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

% for forcing positions of tables, figures, ...
    \usepackage{float}

% units
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{dcolumn}


%% ---------------------------------
%% | ToDo Marker - only for draft! |
%% ---------------------------------
% Remove this section for final version!
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{20mm}

\newcommand{\todo}[1]
{{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{(\margmajortodo{}#1)}}}{}}

\newcommand{\margmajortodo}
{\marginpar{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{ToDo}}}{}}
```

UPDATE:
I found a bypass method on windows by changing `\newcommand{\todo}[1]` to `\renewcommand{\todo}[1]`. However, the changed code give the error of "\todo undefined" on my ubuntu system.

It indicates that the enviroment differs, although the codes are same. What I need to do is find out which package is somehow added/upgraded in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is from `changes` package (as you can see by adding `\show\todo` at various points and seeing where it becomes defined). If you do not need the command from that package simply use `\renewcommand` in your definition to over-ride the existing definition.

Comment: thanks, `\renewcommand` works well in case of conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the final version?  If so, comment out at least the 2 lines that define your command:

```
%\newcommand{\todo}[1]
%{{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{(\margmajortodo{}#1)}}}{}}
```

Comment: in this way, the function of \todo would be changed by the others' definition.

Comment: Of course.  That is precisely why the ```change``` package has draft and final modes and why the code you quoted is prefaced by the instruction to comment out the code for the final version.